Kafka Debezium Oracle Source Connector Intermittent Lag & Data Delay
I am working with Kafka, and we are using Debezium to capture CDC (Change Data Capture) data from an Oracle source database. Below are my Debezium configuration parameters:
{
    "name": "debezium-xstream",
    "config":
    {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
        "database.user": "username",
        "database.password": "pass",
        "database.hostname": "IP",
        "database.port": "Port",
        "database.dbname": "dbname",
        "database.pdb.name": "pdbName",
        "database.server.name": "serverName",
        "heartbeat.interval.ms" : 60000,
        "heartbeat.action.query" : "UPDATE tablename SET d = SYSDATE",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.vaulcard",
        "table.include.list": "TableNames",
       "log.mining.batch.size.min": 500,
       "log.mining.batch.size.max": 2000,
       "log.mining.batch.size.default": 1000,
        "database.history.store.only.captured.tables.ddl" : true,
        "snapshot.select.statement.overrides" : "TableName",
        "snapshot.select.statement.overrides.TableName : "select * from TableName",
        "database.out.server.name": "serverName",
        "key.converter": "/path/to/avro.converter",
        "key.converter.apicurio.registry.url": "/path/to/avro.converter",
        "key.converter.apicurio.registry.auto-register": "true",
        "key.converter.apicurio.registry.find-latest": "false",
        "key.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
        "value.converter": "/path/to/avro.converter",
        "value.converter.apicurio.registry.url": "/path/to/avro.converter",
        "value.converter.apicurio.registry.auto-register": "true",
        "value.converter.apicurio.registry.find-latest": "false",
        "value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
        "converters": "numbertolong",
        "numbertolong.type": "org.example.mongodb.kafka.connect.converters.OracleNumberToLong",
        "numbertolong.selector": ".*tablename.ID"
    }
}


Issue:
We are getting real-time data into our topic (with 3 partitions). However, every 6-8 minutes, my AKHQ dashboard shows zero consumer lag and no transactions for about 50-60 seconds, I have created console consumer here as well, so I found that no transaction has drop in topic for around 50-60 seconds (which seems incorrect because we have a constant transaction rate of about one transaction every 50 ms).
After that idle period, a burst of transactions appears, causing the consumer lag to spike to around 2000. It then takes some time for the data to catch up. During this delay, any transactions performed in production show up with a delay of about 2 minutes, which is unacceptable for our use case.
I suspected that issue is with the Debezium source connector as this source connector is not sending transactions to the topic, so I monitored the logs using the following command:
tail -f /path/to/kafka/connect/logs/connect.log | grep "debezium"


When the issue occurs, the Debezium logs also seem to get stuck, suggesting that Debezium isn't receiving data from LogMiner (which reads from Oracle redo logs).
Question:
I'm not sure how to debug this further. Is there a way to figure out why Debezium isn't capturing data for those 50-60 seconds? Any help in diagnosing this issue or suggestions for improving my configuration would be greatly appreciated.

From this note: XStream is considered more reliable but requires a GG license. https://mathiaszarick.wordpress.com/2024/05/24/oracle-to-postgresql-replication-using-debezium-and-platys/
